# When do two matrices have the same exponential?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ hermitean matrices.
When do we have $e^{iA}=e^{iB}$?
Can we somehow classify those pairs of matrices that have the same exponential?

Here are some observations that I made:

- If $A$ and $B$ commute, then the condition is satisfied if and only if the spectrum of $A-B$ is contained in $2\pi\mathbb Z$. (Both directions can fail if $A$ and $B$ don't commute, as the following two points show.)
- The condition $e^{iA}=e^{iB}$ can also be satisfied if $A$ and $B$ do not commute.
  Take, for example, $A=2\pi\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=2\pi\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$.
  They do not commute but $e^{iA}=e^{iB}=I$.
  The spectrum of their difference is not in $2\pi\mathbb Z$.
- If $A=\sqrt2\pi\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\sqrt2\pi\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then the eigenvalues of $A-B$ are $\pm2\pi$ but $e^{iA}\neq e^{iB}$.
- The exponential map is not a homomorphism so finding the kernel is not enough; cf. the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).
- Having the same exponential is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a rather cheap answer to this question. Let $E_\lambda$ denote the eigenspace of $\lambda \in \mathrm{spec}(A)$.  Let $F_\lambda$ denote the eigenspace of $\lambda \in \mathrm{spec}(B)$. Then $\exp(iA) =\exp(iB)$ if and only if, for every $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$\bigoplus_{\lambda \in \mathrm{spec}(A) \cap (\lambda_0 + 2 \pi \mathbb{Z})} E_\lambda = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \mathrm{spec}(B) \cap (\lambda_0 + 2 \pi \mathbb{Z})} F_\lambda.$$

Roughly speaking, the condition is that $A$ and $B$ should have the same eigenspaces, after identifying the eigenvalues whose exponentials are equal.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! A similar solution occurred to me last night, but I think I won't write it up since we already have this one.

Comment: No problem! Of course, this isn't a particularly deep characterization. I guess a similar thing works if $A$ and $B$ are just normal and $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is any continuous function (instead of $f(t) = e^{it}$).